# Conversão de número com vírgula para numeric no R

Tags: r, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

Tenho um script que recebe um valor do usuário, via `readLines`. Esse valor é um número (valor monetário) com duas casas decimais que deve ser salvo em um data frame.

Porém, quando converto o valor recebido para numeric, o R arredonda para inteiro.

```
valor <- readLines("stdin", n = 1)
valor <- sub(",", ".", valor)#troca vírgula por ponto
valor <- as.numeric(as.character(valor))
```

Também já tentei com `type.convert`, mas o mesmo comportamento acontece.

Comment: Quando tu diz "Esse valor é um número (valor monetário)", isso significa que o usuário entra com um valor tipo `R$ 3,14` ou ele entra com `3,14` direto?

Comment: entra 3,14, por isso que eu utilizo ```sub``` para trocar a vírgula por ponto. Eu vi que  ´´´type.convert``` tem um parâmetro ```dec``` para indicar o caractere decimal, porém ele também arredonda o resultado.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, o R não está arredondando o valor, ele só não exibe todas as casas decimais conforme pode ser visto nesta resposta [Convert character to number without the loss of decimal in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240333/convert-character-to-number-without-the-loss-of-decimal-in-r)

Incluindo o parâmetro `digits` em `print`, vemos que as casas decimais estão lá. O mesmo acontece se salvarmos o data frame para CSV.

Então, se usarmos `valor <- type.convert(valor, dec = ",")` e mostrarmos com `print(valor, digits = 15)` as casas decimais são exibidas corretamente.

Se aplicarmos `print(sum(df$valor), digits = 15)`obteremos o valor correto exibido corretamente.